# Monthly recurring event on specific date

Tags: javascript, date, dayjs

I want to create a recurring date that repeats monthly

For e.g:

A user select a date “2022-09-16”

the ouput should be :

```
[“2022-09-16”, ”2022-10-16”,”2022-11-16”,”2022-12-16”]
```

I have no idea how to implement using dayjs and dayjs-recur

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can initiate a date by the starting day.
After that iterate 3 times, and every time add one month to it then push a new string to the resulting array.

```js
const getDates = str => {
  const dates = [str];
  const date = new Date(str);
  for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
    dates.push(date.toISOString().substring(0, 10));
  }
  return dates;
}

console.log( getDates('2022-09-16') );
```

Comment: I forget to mention I want to achieve it by using dayjs.js and dayjs.recur, could you please give me tips to achieve it ?

Comment: You can research the alternative functions using dayjs like adding a month, getting the string...

Comment: @Achraf—put additional information in the OP.